# Автоматизация публикации в Drupal через Rules and Workflow

Tags: модули, rules, workflow

сейчас я работаю над автоматизацией изменений статусов в Друпале, моя задача состоит в том чтобы используя Rules and Workflow модули настроить смену статусов через определенный период.
Для лучшего понимания приведу пример: мне нужно, чтобы Статья из состояния Черновик автоматически перешла в состояние На проверке через определенный период времени после создания Статьи (например, 24 часа).
Проблема заключается в том, что работать с модулем Rules на 9 версии Друпала гораздо сложнее для меня, чем на 7 версии, поскольку сам модуль недоработан.

**Я попробовала**:

- установить дополнительные модули, которые бы улучшили работу Rules, например Rules Extras. С ним исчезло много ошибок в процессе разработки.
- Также я попробовала установить специальные модули для откладывания - Scheduler и дополнительные к нему. Это помогло отложить дату публикации, но если статус не предусматривает публикации (На Проверке), то он бесполезен.

Несмотря на все, я уверена, что это возможно, однако способ тяжелый и хитрый. Буду благодарна за любую помощь!